# Strange hyperref Info in log file

Tags: hyperref, logging

What could be the source of the following message contained in my log file?

> Package hyperref Info: bookmark level for unknown unnumbered defaults
>   to 0 on input line 48.

I should say that input line 48 and the lines before and after it only contain text, formulas and a blank line. There is a labelled equation environment but if I delete this, the message is still there (the label is the only thing which could possibly be connected with hyperref). I cannot reproduce the message if I compile these lines alone.

Comment: Can you provide an MWE? Code to reproduce the issue would be very helpful.

Comment: Well, as I said, I tried but failed to reproduce the issue in an MWE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have something that writes an entry in one of the list files (table of contents, list of
figures, list of ...) with level "unnumbered". It is not the list (usually the table of contents) that is used for the bookmarks, otherwise it would be a warning. Thus you can ignore this info message. Or you can provide a definition for this level to suppress the message, e.g.:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\toclevel@unnumbered}{0}%
\makeatother
```

Comment: Ah, OK. Then it's maybe caused by `\usepackage{chngcntr}\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}` since the only lists I have are toc, ptc (from titletoc) and lof. But there is no figure in the indicated input lines.

Comment: My guess would be `titletoc` then.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a lot of issues with this. The correction I saw here didn't work for me, and from reading the hyperref readme, I finally got the code I needed.

From the hyperref readme: 
Warning "bookmark level for unknown  defaults to 0"
Getting rid of it:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\toclevel@<foobar>}{0}
\makeatother
```

So for me, the fix was:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\toclevel@unnumberedsection}{0}
\makeatother
```

Comment: There is supposed to be <stuff> that was taken out, for some reason, when I posted. Here is what it was supposed to be: From the hyperrer readme: Warning "bookmark level for unknown <stuff> defaults to 0" Getting rid of it: \makeatletter \providecommand*{\toclevel@}<stuff>{0} \makeatother

So for me, the fix was: \makeatletter \providecommand*{\toclevel@unnumberedsection}{0} \makeatother